# Xamarin Android: Error inflating class

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I converted the [CompactCalendarView library](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView) to a  C# Binding Library using Xamarin. It worked and I am able to access the Namespace via using within my C# code.

Now I want to use the alternative calendar view, the library offers, within my designer (axml) code but I always receive this error:

> Error inflating class Com.Github.Sundeepk.Compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView

Using the class in C# works perfectly fine. However, this is how I tried using the class as a view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
  <include
         android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:id="@+id/toolbar"
         layout="@layout/Toolbar" />
  <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
    <Com.Github.Sundeepk.Compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  />
  </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Full code as an GitHub rep: https://github.com/timozander/xamarin-bug

I tried all case variations for the class (e.g. java-based `com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView` or C#-like `Com.Github.Sundeepk.Compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView`)

I simply can't guess my mistake. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use the java-based namespace (package name) `com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView` for the class

Comment: I tried all case variations, but the error still occurs. Should have mentioned this.

Comment: Have you validated that your include file is correct? Remove it and test again with Java-based package name for `CompactCalendarView`

Comment: I completly rebuild the package and it still does not work within the axml

Comment: You will want to add a `[Register]` attribute to the `CompactCalendarView` and use java-based namespace above by SushiHangover.

Comment: The binding library generated this attribute: `[global::Android.Runtime.Register ("com/github/sundeepk/compactcalendarview/CompactCalendarView", DoNotGenerateAcw=true)]`. Replacing this causes another error to occur

Comment: Ah it's a binding library. I see now. Have you tried to follow the sample layout? https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/main_tab.xml#L8-L19 Can you also post the full error in question? (I.e. The full stack trace of the exception)

Comment: Do you mean the Code Stack? There, the last called method is `SetContentView`. The sample code doesn't work either

Comment: It might be a good idea to upload your current binding and sample project to github for anyone else to dig further in.

Comment: I uploaded the project here: https://github.com/timozander/xamarin-bug

Comment: You have uploaded the Android project having the Binding Project's dll. However, we would also need to check the Bindings Project.